# Regex multiline match from specific word until the first match of an end character

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
foo
 1
 2
 3
 bar
!
!
 2
 3
 bar
!
```

And I would like to match:

```
foo
 1
 2
 3
 bar
!
```

My current regex is `(?s)foo.*!` , but that matched everything

Here is my regex example:

https://regex101.com/r/MBbHnr/1

Comment: What's the rule here?

Comment: @Sweeper As usual, `(?s)foo.*?!`